# Drupal Content changes to Plain text on Cron run

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I add content to an article (either administrator or as content user) and I save the changes as Full HTML or Filtered HTML.
Once I run CRON,the article is marked updated and when I preview it i see **plain text** instead of HTML.Some sort of over writing is taking place which I am unable to figure out.Earlier I thought it was a problem with the webform module but it is not.I tried disabling the modules one by one but was not able to detect the problem.

Comment: Edited just now.I thought the problem is solved but it was not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you check your content under the same user ? I can hardly believe it's a time related issue. It seems more like a rights problem. Do all the relevant roles have access to the input filter Full HTML ?

Comment: Yes.In fact I have removed all permissions for "filtered HTML" and gave the users and admin the "full html" permissions.

Comment: Do you think it is possible for content to revert back that way to "filtered html".I ask this because I am pretty sure that the content is in full html as expected as soon as i update it.

Comment: It's probably possible, but I've never seen this. Short of an automatic backup restoring itself, I can't see how an input filter  change could happen without human action.

Comment: I will check once again.Thanks.Where can I check if there is some automated thing going on?

Comment: Well, it's difficult to say, but I would have a look at anything involving cron and/or Actions/Triggers.

Comment: When I make a content change to a page it saves ok, and then some time later switches to Filtered HTML and removes the Summary, and then after I fix it a few times, it stops having problems until I update the content in the Body again.
 I have been unable to figure out what causes the problem and what makes it stop.
  Could it be something to do with the way the content vs admin is set up?

Comment: I have figured out when this is happening... Whenever I run cron, the summaries are disappearing.. and this results in the switch from Full html to Filtered Html. My body is as it is and all I need to do is to copy the content from body and paste in summary...Is there any wasy I can avoid this ??

Comment: I think a module must do something to your content, and you have to find out which one. Do you use any workflow related module ? Or maybe something which periodically published or marks nodes ?

Comment: I am pretty sure something is wrong with the webform module.. Every time I update a page and run cron, I get these 3 errors for each article I update:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$webform in webform_check_record() (line 2950 of /home/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$webform in webform_check_record() (line 2962 of /home/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$webform in webform_node_update() (line 1028 of /home/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module).

Comment: Whenever an update is made or content is edited, ('updated' or 'new') appears beside the article. Now if I view that article from within drupal and make ('updated' or 'new') disappear,and then run cron, I **bold**do not**bold** see this issue.
So it is only when I do not view content from withing drupal this problem is seen.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You mean, you see the problem only when you're not authenticated ? If it's the case, then you have a problem with user permissions, Anonymous not having access to your Full HTML format.

Comment: No.It is not just anonymous .Even the authenticated face the same problem even with permissions.
It is just that cron throws the above errors related to the webform module if the content is not previewed before cron runs.

Comment: The issue with Webform belongs in its issue queue, where I saw you already posted. I don't think it may be related to the input format switch, though, but I don't use Webform so I may be wrong.

Comment: Another obervation i made is that after I run cron along with the "updated" tag appearing the updated time is also changed to the time when cron runs.

Comment: I think the problem is with the cmis module.This is what I did.
I created a new article and saved it as Full HTML and ran cron.The content switched to Plain text as expected.Then I deleted the article from within drupal.and ran cron again,Then cmis threw an error and the deleted article reappeared in drupal.
Then suddenly,after 7PM ish everything started working as expected,no content switch,no "updated" marks etc.
I remember the similar thing happening few days back,where the problem disappeared after 7 PMish. Do you think there is a timer running somewhere?
Please let me know.. Thanks

Comment: CMIS seems definitely capable of changing weird things on your content, and your tests prove it. It seems to be a big beast, and I'm not familiar with it. A quick glance at the code reveals a function in cmis_sync called `_cmis_sync_cmis_drupal_handle_updates` which definitely updates nodes (line 101). It's an old dev version, so I would advise you to post in the issue queue(http://drupal.org/project/issues/cmis)